# multiple seekbar values in TextView by implementing onSeekBarChangeListener

Tags: java, android

I'm not able to get multiple SeekBar values in multiple TextViews by implementing OnSeekBarChangeListener interface.

By anonymous class I have implemented this but I want this way for my application.

```
seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
switch (seekBar.getId()){
case R.id.seek1:{
seek1Val=String.valueOf(2000+i*1000);
tvAmount.setText(seek1Val);}
break;
case R.id.seek2:{
seek2Val = String.valueOf(0+i*.5);
tvRate.setText(seek2Val);
}
break;
}
```

I expect output in each TextView for different SeekBar but value of progress I is taking same for every SeekBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better would be to add different `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` for each `SeekBar`.

Or if you don't want that then use `tag` instead `id`

Best would be:

```
 seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                seek1Val=String.valueOf(2000+i*1000);
                tvAmount.setText(seek1Val);}
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

 seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                seek2Val = String.valueOf(0+i*.5);
                tvRate.setText(seek2Val);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```